# Proving that $\lim_{n \to \infty}t_n = s$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm stuck on the following problem:

> $s_n$ and $t_n$ are sequences, such that $s_n=t_n$ except for finitely many values of $n$. Explain why if $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  s_n = s$, then also $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}t_n = s$, using the definition of limit.

Actually, my problem is that I understand that thing, but I can't come up with the idea of using the definition (with $\epsilon$ and $N$) to prove it.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you know that $\lim _{n\to \infty } s_n =s$, given a positive $\epsilon$ you can find an $N$ such that $$n\ge N \implies |s_n - s | < \epsilon$$

On the other hand you can find an $M$ such that $$ n>M \implies s_n=t_n$$

Let $K= \max \{N,M \}$ and  see what happens if $n>K$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Since $s_n=t_n$ except for finitely many values of $n$ a maximum value $\bar n$ exixts such that $s_{\bar n}\neq t_{\bar n}$.

Then refer to the definition of limit.